# Unable to resolve Private Hosted Zone in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I’m having some trouble with Private Hosted Zones on AWS Route 53. I have two VPCs (staging and production) and I'd like to set up a private zone for each one under `*.local`.

What I have done is from the Route 53 console added a Private Hosted Zone for `local.` and added, as an example, a `CNAME` entry for `docker.local` to my hosted docker registry.

At this point, I would expect to be able to ssh into any ec2 instance inside that VPC and successfully `dig docker.local`. However, that's not the case and I continue to receive `NXDOMAIN` responses even a few hours after creating the zone. I’ve made sure to set the DNS options on the VPC as is instructed in a lot of places, but no luck. I feel like I’m possibly misunderstanding how this works as it seems too simple to mess up, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Include your DHCP Options Sets for one of the VPCs in your question. This is where the DNS servers are setup to resolve your private hosted zones.

Comment: Also did you set the VPC ID in the right hand pane (Hosted Zone Details) in Route 53?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the DHCP Option Sets. I wasn't familiar with those -- turns out we're running a custom option set, so that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by a custom DHCP Options Set I didn't know we had. Using the default option set with AWS nameservers fixes the problem (as you would expect).